# I want to search for a file using file extension and parts of a path name in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, find, locate

I am working in an ubuntu terminal, remotely connected to the supercomputer at university and looking for files with the extension '.pha'.

However, the directory I am in has so much information in it, it takes over an hour to search the first folder and its sub-folders. I know my file should be located somewhere with a path name `temperature*/clusters/XMMXCS*/spec/`

where * is the wildcard symbol. There are lots of folders beginning with the word *temperature*, and lots of sub-folders called *clusters* and *spec*.

Is there any way I can get the path directory of all '.pha' files with an unclear path extension such as this?

I have tried `find /temperature*/clusters/XMMXCS*/spec/ -name '*.pha'`
and `ls temperature*/clusters/XMMXCS*/spec/`
and just trying to *cd* into folders with the same path name, but with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of chance, the 'super computer' run `updatedb` once a day (or such), then you can use

```
locate -ir 'temperature.*/clusters/XMMXCS.*/spec/.*\.pha$'
```

as far of this is cached, this is quicker than find.

Comment: Thanks very much! Worked like a charm and did it in seconds! Saved me loads of hassle.

Comment: Maybe think of upvote/accept question if it fit your requirements